# Send alert when online

Tags: javascript

I want to understand how `navigator.onLine` works. For that purpose, I typed up a small snippet, which is supposed to check every 3 seconds if the browser is online, and if it is, pop up an alert:

```
function check_connection() {
var online = navigator.onLine;
return online;
}

function timed_alert() {

var perfectTiming = setInterval(check_connection,3000);

if (online) {
alert("ONLINE!");
clearInterval(perfectTiming);
}

timed_alert();
```

This thing doesn't work, for some reason. What have I done incorrectly? What should I change in the snippet to make it work?

Comment: OH. Of course! Thank you, @F4r-20! So what should I do instead of if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your alert and check need  to be in the same function, along with the timer id (perfectTiming) being global.

```
var perfectTiming = null;
function check_connection() {
     var online = navigator.onLine;
     if (online) {
          alert("ONLINE!");
          clearInterval(perfectTiming);
     }
}

function timed_alert() {
    perfectTiming = setInterval(check_connection,3000);
}

timed_alert();
```

if you are trying to test to see if the user has an active internet connection that is harder as there is no real way for the browser to check this. You could however test several different ip/urls to see if they are reachable

```
var testUrlIndex = 0;
var testurls = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.cnn.com"
];
function testURL(url)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==0)
        {
                testUrlIndex++;
            if( testUrlIndex<testurls.length ) {
                testUrl(testurls[testUrlIndex]);
            } else {
                weAppearToBeOffline();
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function weAppearToBeOffline() {
     //DO whatever you need to do if we are offline.
}
testUrl(testurls[0]); //start the check
```

This code will check 2 urls (just add more urls to `testurls` if u want to check more), if it goes though all of them and cant reach them it will call the `weAppearToBeOffline` function

Now this is only faulty in a couple ways, one mainly being that there is a situation where maybe the user is online but cant reach any of those urls but can reach others .

Comment: Thank you very much, @Patrick – but why does it output the alert even when the browser is online?

Comment: because that is what it is checking, to see if its online, if u want ot check if its offline, use `if (!online) {`   `!` means not, so if online "not true"

Comment: I mistyped, sorry, @Patrick. It outputs the alert even when I unplug the Internet cable (and there's no wireless).

Comment: Edited my answer to include checking of urls to see if the user is offline. but it is potentially able to give a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

make following changes:

```
var perfectTiming = setInterval(check_connection,3000);

function check_connection() {    
  if(navigator.onLine){
      alert("ONLINE!");
      clearInterval(perfectTiming);
  }
}
```

Comment: your timer id variable isnt visible to check_connection :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call timed_alert with a setTimeout and not check_connection.

```
function check_connection() {
    var online = navigator.onLine;
    return online;
}

function timed_alert() {
    var online  =check_connection();


    if (online) {
       alert("ONLINE!");

    }
    else{

       setTimeout(timed_alert,3000);
    }
}
timed_alert();
```

Comment: Why setTimeout, and not setInterval, @Gregoire?

Comment: @KeithRules because it is called in the function that is called by the trigger. If I had used setInterval I would have had a new interval set for each timed_alert function call

Answer (score 2):

Your checking for the connection every 3 seconds, but your not doing anything with it. Call the `timed_alert` every 3 seconds instead and use `check_connection` within that function:

```
var perfectTiming = setInterval(timed_alert,3000);

function check_connection() {
    var online = navigator.onLine;
    return online;
}

function timed_alert() {
    if (check_connection()) {
        alert("ONLINE!");
        clearInterval(perfectTiming);
    }
}
```

This is the route to take if you plan to `check_connection` elsewhere in your script.

Comment: Solved? Glad to have helped.

Comment: Almost works... except it outputs the alert even if there's no Internet connection. Am I missing something, @F4r-20?

Comment: @KeithRules Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779367/navigator-online-still-true-when-turning-off-wifi-false-when-set-work-offline) (:

Comment: So, am I understanding correctly that I have to set Work Offline variable to true when check_connection returns false? Or am I misinterpreting the answer from that question, @F4r-20?

Comment: The navigator.onLine does not use the network connectivity of the machine itself, it uses the 'Work Offline' option in most browsers. Even if the computer has no connectivity, the 'Work Offline' option can still equal false.

Comment: Damn, this is getting confusing. Sorry, @F4r-20, I'm a JavaScript novice. What should I modify in the script to make the browser send alert when there's no connection?

Comment: You can't, not with `navigator.onLine` anyway. You'd have to make an AJAX request to an online server and check for a response every, 3 seconds, for example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32497/discussion-between-f4r-20-and-keithrules)